# How to fix colon error with if statement in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a syntax error I can't see it. Here is my code.

I am creating a piece of code which allows the user to enter a correct pin in Python. I tried adding an if statement and I keep getting a syntax error on the colon.

This for a Python test. I have tried re indenting and removing the colon, but nothing has seemed to work.

```
running=True
name=input("What is your name")
pin=int(input("what is the pin"))
if pin==("1234"):
     print ("welcome the northen frock")
else:running=False
```

I expect it to print if pin is correct print "welcome to northen frock".

Comment: Add your code as text instead of sharing image

Comment: Do not include links! Instead provide you code as `formatted text`.

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error, the traceback should tell you where it is.

Comment: You're missing a parentheses on line 3. Flagging to close this since it was caused due to a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead the last line of your code

```
 else:running=False
```

Write

```
 else:
     running = False
```

Also in the first line of code replace it with

```
running = True
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: The former snippet is valid Python syntax in OP's context. :)

Comment: Oh ok didnt know

Comment: i have a new problem now it says running is not defiened

Comment: Plz paste whole code so i can understand and help you

Comment: running = True
name=input("what is your name")
pin=(int(input("what is the pin")))
if pin == ("1234") :
    print("welcome to northen frock")
 else:
     running = False

Comment: The error is that while taking input you have converted it to int and then in if loop you compare it to a string

Comment: Try this code. i have replaced inputs with dummy values

Comment: running = True 
name="xyz"
pin=12
if pin == 1234 : 
    print("welcome to northen frock") 
else: 
    running = False

Answer (score 0):

I worked this script. Try this.(Python 2.7.15)

```
running=True
name=raw_input("What is your name")
pin=raw_input("what is the pin")
if pin==("1234"):
     print ("welcome the northen frock")
else:
    running=False
```

Python 3 is:

```
    running=True
    name=input("What is your name")
    pin=input("what is the pin")
    if pin==("1234"):
         print ("welcome the northen frock")
    else:
        running=False
```

Comment: raw_input is not defined

Comment: What is your python version? Python 3 or 2

Comment: i have got python version 3

Comment: So you try `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: Edit my post according to Python 3